# How Can i Create This Complicated Query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join

I have 3 tables: projects, skills and project_skills. In projects table i hold project's general data. Second table skills i hold skill id and skill name also i have projects_skills table which is hold project's skill relationships. Here is scheme of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_skills` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `skill_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  KEY `skill_id` (`skill_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_description` text COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_budget` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_allowedtime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_deadline` datetime NOT NULL,
  `total_bids` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `average_bid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `employer_id` (`employer_id`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `project_title` (`project_title`,`project_description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `seo_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `total_projects` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `seo_name` (`seo_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=224 ;
```

**I want to select projects with related skill names. I think i have to use JOIN but i don't know how can i do. Thanks**

Comment: It's worth reading a SQL Tutorial as a refresher. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Please give an example of "related skill names".

Comment: Skill id - Project id relationship holds in project skill names but i want skill names that holds in skills table. I mean these skill names by saying "related skill names"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a `JOIN` is exactly right:

```
SELECT ...
FROM projects
INNER JOIN project_skills ON (project_skills.project_id = projects.id)
INNER JOIN skills ON (skills.id = project_skills.skill_id)
```

Comment: That will only return projects with skills associated, not related skill names

Comment: Names of skills are stored in skills.name column; if the names are desired that column can simply be added to the list of fields `SELECT`ed

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from projects
left join project_skills on projects.id = project_skills.project_id
left join skills on project_skills.skills_id = skills .id
```

note: you don't need all columns, but this will let you see what is going on before you pick the columns you need.

Comment: That will only return projects with skills associated, not related skill names

Comment: @OMG : I believe it will return skills.name please explain